# How to add user id taken from JWT to the backend logs via MDC?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-sleuth, mdc

We have a spring boot application with REST interface and a web client. We are using spring-security with **OAuth 2.0 JWT** tokens for authentication. We are using slf4j and sleuth for logging. We want to log the currently logged-in user id in our logs. Technically, we want to add the user id to the **Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)** of our server application.

The goal is to link server side errors resulting from frontend operations to the user who has triggerend the backend operation.

At the moment, we extract the user id on the client side and send the id as HTTP header field to the server where it is extraced from the HTTP header as baggage by sleuth and added to the logs, see following `spring.sleuth.baggage` configuration. This is working.

```
spring.sleuth.baggage.remote-fields=user_id
spring.sleuth.baggage.tag-fields=user_id
spring.sleuth.baggage.correlation-fields=user_id
```

The user is logged by `user=%X{user_id:-}`, see the full log pattern:

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: WARN
  pattern:
    console: "[%d] [%t] %highlight(%-5p) %c{10} - %cyan([trace=%X{X-B3-TraceId:-} span=%X{X-B3-SpanId:-} user=%X{user_id:-}]) %m%n"
```

However, instead of extracting the user id on the client side and sending it to the backend, we want to directly extract the user id from the JWT token on the server side. Since all the information are also directly available on the server side.

I have checked spring-cloud-sleuth documentation how to set baggage fields in Java, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#java-configuration
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/project-features.html#features-brave-baggage
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/appendix.html#appendix

I did not know which classes to use and how to use them. I've tried the following code. The code is not executed at Spring startup. So, it seems some config is missing or the code is completely wrong.

```
package net.company.common.service;

import brave.baggage.BaggageField;
import brave.baggage.BaggagePropagation;
import brave.baggage.BaggagePropagationConfig;
import brave.baggage.BaggagePropagationCustomizer;
import brave.internal.baggage.BaggageContext;
import net.company.common.service.CommonServiceConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Import({CommonServiceConfig.class})
public class ServiceConfig {

  @Bean
  BaggagePropagationConfig.SingleBaggageField singleBaggageField() {
    BaggagePropagationConfig.SingleBaggageField field = BaggagePropagationConfig.SingleBaggageField.newBuilder(BaggageField.create("user_id")).build();
    field.field().updateValue("user_12345"); // set only dummy value for debug
    return field;
  }

}
```

It would be possible to implement such an MDC manually, see https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback. But as this is error prone we want to avoid it, e.g. context cleaning must be done right.

How can the user id from JWT be added to MDC using sleuth/brave for server side logging?

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
spring boot version: 2.1.2.RELEASE
spring cloud version: Greenwich.RELEASE
```

and you can configure with following properties

```
spring.sleuth.propagation-keys=user_id
spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.whitelisted-mdc-keys=user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
spring.sleuth.baggage.remote-fields=user_id
```

and it's working for you, this is how to create and update the value of Baggage Fields.

```
    BaggageField baggageField = BaggageField.create(baggageKey);
    baggageField.updateValue(baggageValue);
```

Do note that updating baggage value this way will show up in the logs from the next span. In case you want to update the value in the same span have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67373784/2224254

Answer (score 0):

You can get the principal (username in your case) from Spring Security like this (assuming you are using the JWT as it should be):

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

After this, you can add it to the MDC or set as a baggage field/tag/etc:

```java
// assuming username is setup in sleuth.baggage.remote-keys
BaggageField USERNAME = BaggageField.create("username");

USERNAME.updateValue(span.context(), String.valueOf(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()));
Tags.BAGGAGE_FIELD.tag(USERNAME, span);
```