# Spring cloud sleuth adding tag

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, datadog, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm trying to implement distributed tracing in my kotlin app using spring cloud sleuth.
I'm sending those data to the datadog. Now I'm able to trace my logs but I want to add some extra data to spans. Let's say I want to add info about user and be able to see it in datadog. Am I right that span tags are good for it? I'm sending the logs in json format to datadog but I cannot add tags here. (traceId and spanId are injected).
Logback config:

```
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp/>
                <version/>
                <message/>
                <loggerName/>
                <threadName/>
                <logLevel/>
                <logLevelValue/>
                <callerData/>
                <stackTrace/>
                <rootStackTraceElement/>
                <context/>
                <mdc/>
                <tags/>
                <logstashMarkers/>
                <arguments/>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
```

gradle:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6")
implementation("org.zalando:logbook-spring-boot-starter:2.4.2")
developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
runtimeOnly("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog")
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
```

and to add the tag I'm trying

```
@NewSpan
fun newSpanTest() {
    tracer.currentSpan()!!.tag("user", "123")
    log.info("other span")
    otherTestService.sameSpanTest()
}
```

example log:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-03-09T21:04:46.953+01:00","@version":"1","message":"other span","logger_name":"com.microservices.text.rpg.servicediscovery.TestService","thread_name":"http-nio-8761-exec-3","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"caller_class_name":"com.microservices.text.rpg.servicediscovery.TestService","caller_method_name":"newSpanTest","caller_file_name":"TestService.kt","caller_line_number":25,"traceId":"e61fd165d7c84776","spanId":"5e61f9b51b51619b"}
```

shouldn't be that 'user' injected into MDC and then into logs?

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

`spring.sleuth.baggage.correlation-fields` automatically sets baggage values to Slf4j’s MDC so you only need to set the baggage field.

### Longer version with background

I suppose you use Sleuth out of the box (uses Brave):

1. Fist get familiar with [tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-terminology), [baggage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-baggage) and their [differences](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-baggage-vs-tags); you can also read about them in [Brave docs](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/brave#baggage)
2. Check Brave's [`ScopeDecorator`](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/5be287b91c3d18da9fc7a597d71b12b27be6043c/brave/src/main/java/brave/propagation/CurrentTraceContext.java#L176), [`CorrelationScopeDecorator`](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/5be287b91c3d18da9fc7a597d71b12b27be6043c/brave/src/main/java/brave/baggage/CorrelationScopeDecorator.java#L28) and [`MDCScopeDecorator`](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/5be287b91c3d18da9fc7a597d71b12b27be6043c/context/slf4j/src/main/java/brave/context/slf4j/MDCScopeDecorator.java#L25)

The `spring.sleuth.baggage.correlation-fields` property automatically sets baggage values to Slf4j’s MDC so you only need to set the baggage field.

Also, using `MDCScopeDecorator`, you can set the baggage values to Slf4j’s MDC programmatically, you can see how to do it in [Sleuth docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-baggage):

```java
// configuration
@Bean
BaggageField countryCodeField() {
    return BaggageField.create("country-code");
}

@Bean
ScopeDecorator mdcScopeDecorator() {
    return MDCScopeDecorator.newBuilder()
            .clear()
            .add(SingleCorrelationField.newBuilder(countryCodeField())
                    .flushOnUpdate()
                    .build())
            .build();
}

// service
@Autowired
BaggageField countryCodeField;

countryCodeField.updateValue("new-value");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I noticed that for values that I want to distribute between services I can use baggage but if I want to have data only in span scope I should use tags, right?
For example I want to have those info in logs:
`{span: "span-1" command: "command-1", user: "user1"}
{span: "span-2" command: "command-2", user: "user1"}
{span: "db-request-span", user: "user1"}`
value over command key should be a tag and user should be baggage? I can easily add baggage but have problems with tags. Should sleuth take care of adding values to MDC and removing them on span create/remove?

Comment: Yes, that's why I put the first item there: baggage is propagated throughout spans, tags are not, also, tags are sent to the tracing backend (Zipkin). I guess that's why the `MDCScopeDecorator` only supports baggage and not tags.
Please notice that these classes are not in Sleuth, Sleuth just abstracts away the tracing library (in this case Brave). If you think that feature should be implemented, you can open a new issue in Brave: https://github.com/openzipkin/brave