# How do I setup baggage fields in Spring Cloud Sleuth for a Command Line Runner?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, command-line, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm successfully using Spring Cloud Sleuth in a Spring Boot microservice and am having fields logged and sent over http headers appropriately.

I now need to integrate this same process for logging and header propagation in a Spring Boot command line runner application but it looks like no trace and span are automatically setup since it isn't in the middle of an Http request (as it is a command line app). I cannot see these fields in my logs (with the same %X format in log configuration).

I've looked at the docs and can't find any examples for this specific use case. Is this possible in a command line runner app?

Answer (score 2):

In order to add baggage you need to have a span. Spring Cloud Sleuth and Spring Boot create a span for you when the controller is invoked. If you want to do the same using CLI application, you need to create span yourself.

You have two options.

[Using API calls](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using-creating-and-ending-spans):

```java
Span span = this.tracer.nextSpan().name("mySpan");
// do some work
span.end(); // best to put it in finally to make sure span is always ended
```

Or you [can use annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using-annotations):

```java
@NewSpan
public void doWork() {
}
```

If you use the annotation, please keep in mind the [AOP proxies limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies). In particular self invocations (calls using `this`) would not work.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsoleApplication 
  implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        doWork(); //this is the same as this.doWork();
    }

    @NewSpan
    public void doWork() {
    }
}
```

This is not going to work as `doWork` is not invoked through the AOP proxy. Make sure that you annotate a component managed by Spring and then use an injected instance.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsoleApplication 
  implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        myService.doWork();
    }

}

@Component
class MyService {

    @NewSpan
    public void doWork() {
    }

}
```

In this case `myService` is not instance of `MyService`, but rather an instrumented proxy.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the follow up! The manual tracer setup actually got me part of the way there but it looks like I wasn't able to log anything because of expecting the default template to work while I was using Log4J2 (per https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2008) so changing my format got the trace and span ids.

Unfortunately, when I add baggage fields via the tracer they do not get added to subsequent WebClient (a bean) calls as baggage would in the context of a request. A scope decorator did it for logs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66554834/16800757